# Core-Bluetooth get wrong characters back as answers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

i need to develop an app wich can communticate with a peripheral and i use a BlueGigaModul. Basically i send commands and wait for the answere. Ive the problem that the response is not correct. The wrong character appears randomly. I send each second a command to my device. To bluetooth module get the correct data but the data i get on the iphone contains wrong characters? The data i get is bigger than 20 bytes but the module should split it.

1.

```
How could this be? Is it because i memcopy to early? 
The method didUpdateValueForCharacteristic is called if the whole data arrived?
```

2.

```
Is it better to writeValue or updateCharacteristic?
```

3.

```
I only find one characteristic? Do i need one to send and one to receive? 
Or do i need to unsubscribe after writeValue and resubscribe for receive data?
```

4.

```
Does CoreBluetooth check if the data is corrupt??
```

this is how i writeValue:

```
    NSString * test = @"\r";
    NSData *data = [test dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    if(hr_characteristic != nil){
        [_discoveredPeripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic: hr_characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

I check the response with:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    if(error != nil)
        return;

    int len=characteristic.value.length;
    if(len != 0)
    {

        memcpy(pbuffer,[characteristic.value bytes],len);
            pbuffer += len;
        }
}
```

Atm i fill the buffer with all the data i receive. I send 10 times. After i received all compare the buffer with my expected answer.

I send 600 commands and have 34 wrong characters in it. The buffer is filled with 5230bytes.

Thanks

Comment: First, at least logging a message if there is an error is probably better than simply throwing it away.  Second you may be sending data too fast and overwriting data in the sending buffer.

Comment: OK i handle the errors now. You mean the receiving buffer? (pbuffer)? I send a command and wait for the response to send the next command. Bluetooth 4.0 supports crc right? so the sent package is delivered correctly? ty paul for your support

Comment: I've characters like [228] char '\x04' '\x04' in my pbuffer and this should not happen

Comment: The corruption may not be happening in the radio link - it could be happening in the connection between your micro controller and your Bluetooth module

Comment: i updated my blue giga module. I modified it before now I've the original firmware on it. Other problems appear now :)